# Problem on returning true or false for each array to compare with one filter array

Tags: javascript

I need to compare an array with a group of arrays (Array of Array) and return `true` on each array that have **all** values of filter value and `false` if even one of filter array is missing in the arrays.

I am using the following code which for sure is not correct way to do this as I am not getting proper result

```js
let selected = [];
let filter = ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'];

let data = [
  ['item-0', 'item-112', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-12', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-31'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3', 'item-3', 'item-3', 'item-3']

];



function checkfilter(arr1, arr2) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
         if(arr2[j].includes(arr1[i])){
           selected.push('1');
         }
         else{
           selected.push('0');
         }
    }
  }
}
checkfilter(filter, data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
data.map(a=> filter.every(f=>a.includes(f)));
```

```js
let selected = [];
let filter = ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'];

let data = [
  ['item-0', 'item-112', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-12', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-31'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3', 'item-3', 'item-3', 'item-3']

];

function checkfilter(filter, data) {
  return  data.map(a=> filter.every(f=>a.includes(f)));
}

console.log(checkfilter(filter, data) );
```

Comment: Thanks for code Kamil, but I need to get the `true` or `false` for each of the arrays in `data`. this way you are comparing entire the `data`

Comment: @Suffii I update answer - now array is return as result

Comment: Thanks a lots, by the way, do u know any good resource to lean this `.map()` in jQuery? I have seen some on web but very comlicated!

Comment: @Suffii map is in pure js (not jquery) - more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to see that **every** value in arr1 is included in at least **some** arrays in arr2. Luckily there are JS functions for that, no jQuery necessary!

```js
let selected = [];
let filter = ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'];

let data = [
  ['item-0', 'item-112', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-12', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-31'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3', 'item-3'],
  ['item-1', 'item-2', 'item-4', 'item-5', 'item-7', 'item-8', 'item-3', 'item-3', 'item-3', 'item-3']

];



function checkfilter(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.every(function(c) {
    return arr2.some(function(a) {
      return a.includes(c);
    });
  });
}
console.log(checkfilter(filter, data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#isEqual) method of lodash :

```
let isFilterExist = false;
data.map(a => {
   // Do Whatever You need To do based on the condition
   if (_.isEqual(a, filter)) {
     isFilterExist = true;
   }
   console.log(isFilterExist)
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2aeuxm56/1/